# How to redirect user to an url when node is flagged?

Tags: 8, rules, flags

My problem is related to the **Drupal 8** versions of these two modules: **rules** and **flag**.

***What I want to achieve***

- Some node types on my site are offering a global flag as a link (for e.g. "report error" flag)
- If the user clicks on it, he should be redirected to a special contact form. The flagged node URL should be submitted to an entity reference field automatically on the contact form too.

***How I solved it in Drupal 7***

In *Drupal 7* there was a rules event "node is flagged" to trigger the redirect action. The flagging URL I could pass via Drupal 7 module "entity reference prepopulate" (which functionality is merged into core reference field in Drupal 8).

In Drupal 8 the rules event "node is flagged" seems not to exist.

Any idea how to realise a behaviour like described above in Drupal 8?

THX in advance,

Phil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the event, **After saving new flagging**

Add Condition of Flag, and enter flag machine name

Add action of Page redirect, enter the url where you want to redirect. Ex: `/node/1`

[image]

**Important**

In your flag settings, you need use a link type of **Normal link**, because it won't work with AJAX

[image]