# How do I redirect on flag save programmatically?

Tags: 8, flags

I want to redirect users to a view when they flag a taxonomy term.

[This question is about how to use Rules to redirect on flag save.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264400/how-to-redirect-user-to-an-url-when-node-is-flagged)  I want to do this programmatically.

I tried to use `hook_form_alter()` to add a submit handler with the redirect.  Unfortunately, while flaggings have an edit form that can be targeted by `hook_form_alter()` (`MYMODULE_form_flagging_FLAGTYPE_edit_form_alter()`), they do not seem to have a "create" form.

So how can I add a redirect programmatically upon flagging?

**EDIT**

Based on 4k4's comment I looked at `/flag/srs/Entity/Flagging.php`:

```
 *    "form" = {
 *      "add" = "Drupal\flag\Form\FlaggingForm",
 *      "edit" = "Drupal\flag\Form\FlaggingForm",
 *      "delete" = "Drupal\flag\Form\UnflagConfirmForm"
```

However, when I tried to do a `hook_form_alter()` with:

- `function MYMODULE_form_flagging_FLAGGINGTYPE_add_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)`
- `function MYMODULE_form_flagging_add_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)`

I could not get either to pick up my code (I rebuilt the cache).

Comment: Yes, this is the right approach, setting a redirect in a form submit handler and it's correct, flaggings don't have a "create" form, but they should have an "add" form by looking at the entity class.

Comment: @4k4 Thanks for the tip.  I looked at the class and there is an "add" form, but I can't get it to hit with `hook_form_alter()` for some reason. (Question edited)

Comment: I find the naming scheme of that specific hook quite confusing, too. You can take a different approach using the general form alter hook and narrowing down the new entity step by step. I add it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a different approach to target entity forms:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityFormInterface;


/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form_object = $form_state->getFormObject();
  if (!($form_object instanceof ContentEntityFormInterface)) {
    return;
  }

  $entity = $form_object->getEntity();
  if (!(entity instanceof FooEntityInterface)) {
    return;
  }

  if (!$entity->isNew()) {
    return;
  }

  if ($entity->bundle() !== 'bar') {
    return;
  }

  // alter form
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in `hook_entity_presave()`.

```
function MYMODULE_flagging_presave(FlaggingInterface $flagging) {
  switch ($flagging->getFlagId()) {
    case 'FLAGTYPE':
      $redirect_url = Url::fromRoute('view.VIEW_MACHINE_NAME.VIEW_DISPLAY_ID')->toString();
      $response = new RedirectResponse($redirect_url);
      $response->send();
     break;
   }
 }
```